# Where is chacha20 and chacha_poly_aead used in Bitcoin Core?

Tags: bitcoin-core-development, cryptography, bip324-p2p-encryption

In the source code of Bitcoin Core there are these functions but no explanation of how and where they are used. I need to make a description for all crypto-functions used in Bitcoin Core (https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/tree/master/src/crypto) but it's difficult to find information, so asking you here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can open the git history for each file and see when and why they were added.

chacha20.cpp was added in [PR #9792](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/9792), apparently to improve Bitcoin Core's random number generator. chacha_poly_aead.cpp was added in [PR #15649](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/15649) as a preliminary step for implementing [BIP324](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/pull/1378) (the P2P encrypted transport protocol).